# mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string error in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I am using WordPress for one of my website,and suddenly i got this error while logging which was working fine before.

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   object given in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1105

This is the function which is causing issue.

```
function _real_escape( $string ) {

    if ( $this->dbh ) {
        if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
            $escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbh, $string );
        } else {
            $escaped = mysql_real_escape_string( $string, $this->dbh );

        }

        $escaped = addslashes( $string );
    }

    return $this->add_placeholder_escape( $escaped );
}
```

Note: my current PHP version is 5.6

Comment: The `mysql_*` part should be removed and the `mysqli_*` part should be kept. To be fair, you shouldn't need either if you are using prepared statements.

Comment: I know your issue is with `mysqli_*`, but since you have both in your code, be aware that the `mysql_*` functions are badly obsolete and in fact no longer exist in newer PHP versions. This therefore definitely needs to be removed if you plan to support PHP7+. Additionally, `addslashes` does pretty much the same thing (though not as good) as the two `_real_escape_string` functions, so by calling that as well as them, you're double-escaping your data. That's pretty poor practice and can lead to further issues. (mind you, WordPress has a tendency to encourage this kind of bad practice. eugh)

Answer (score 2):

you need to change

```
$escaped = mysql_real_escape_string( $string, $this->dbh );
```

With

```
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbh, $string);
```

because here you are using `mysqli`

```
if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
            $escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->dbh, $string );
        }
```

And here you are using `mysql`

```
else {
   $escaped = mysql_real_escape_string( $string, $this->dbh );

}
```

and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` expects first parameter should be database connection  but here given parameter is  `$string`.which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to a WordPress file. If it would mention a WPML file it would be much easier to debug.

Could you try:

1. Open your wp-config.php
2. Add these three lines in there:

   ```
   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
   define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
   ```
3. Then call one of these problematic pages again
4. Copy and paste the contents of `wp-content/debug.log` on `pastebin.com` for us to see

Hopefully the `debug.log` gives us some clues what happened immediately before this error.